# Firebase Cloud Function onWrite trigger firing multiple times

Tags: angular, firebase, nodemailer, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a contact form on my website that writes to a Real-time Database. Using Cloud Functions, I want to respond to the database entry by sending myself an email with that contacts details.

I've confirmed that I am only sending the payload once and the data is being written to the database perfectly fine. The problem I'm having is that the onWrite responds to every line of entry to the database e.g. I send name, email, company and message, therefore, my function invokes 4 times. I'm NOT re-writing to the database which, I'm aware performs another invocation. A line of data is received on each invocation as single values, I don't get an object of all the values as 'promised' in the documentation. I have also tried onCreate, which wasn't even invoked.

Am I misinformed? Is this expected behaviour? Any help appreciated.

The code...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database
  .ref('/messages/{pushKey}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    // Only send email for new messages.
    if (!snapshot.exists()) { return null; }

    const val = snapshot.val();

    console.log(val);
  });
```

My class that posts to 'messages'...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

export interface Item { name: string; email: string; message: string; html: string; date: string }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})
export class ContactComponent {
      public rForm: FormGroup;
      public post: any;
      public message: string = '';
      public name: string = '';
      public company: string = '';
      public email: string = '';
      itemRef: AngularFireObject<any[]>;
      item;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.createForm();
    this.itemRef = db.object('messages');
    this.item = this.itemRef.valueChanges();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.rForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      email: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      message: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(15)])],
      validate: ''
    });
  }

  sendMessage(post) {

    this.name = post.name;
    this.email = post.email;
    this.message = post.message;

    const item: Item = {
      name: post.name,
      email: post.email,
      message: post.message,
      html: `You were contacted from your website by ${post.name}. They said "${post.message}". You can contact them back on ${post.email}`,
      date: Date()
    };

    this.itemRef.update(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that writes to `/messages`

Comment: While it's theoretically possible that a function gets triggered multiple times, I haven't seen that happen. As Bob asked, please update your question to include the code that triggers the function. Also: if indeed the function gets triggered multiple times it should also do so if you don't use `nodemailer`, but for example just a `console.log` statement in the body. That would significantly simplify the problem, since we can stop considering email as a potential cause. Read [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on such things.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anyone is as dumb as me but, I was writing to the same location in my DB. 1 entry only ever existed so I was 'changing' 4 items of data therefore I would trigger 4 onWrite events.

I resolved this by creating a new entry in the database under a unique folder.